# using setInterval in angularjs factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-framework

I was trying the code given in angularjs docs (given here: http://jsfiddle.net/zGqB8/)
It just implements a time factory and uses $timeout to update the time object after each second.

```
angular.module('timeApp', [])
.factory('time', function($timeout) {
    var time = {};

    (function tick () {
        time.now = new Date().toString();
        $timeout(tick, 1000);  // how to do it using setInterval() ?
    })();

    return time;
});
```

How would I do it using setInterval() function instead of $timeout() ?
I know that one need to use `scope.$apply()` to enter the angular execution context but how would that work in a factory function? I mean, in a controller, we have a scope, but we don't have scope in a factory function?

Comment: why do you need to use setInterval? This achieves the same results.

Comment: I like your current solution.

Comment: @LiviuT. yes, it works here but I just wanted to know how will I enter angular execution context when inside a factory function.

Comment: Angular now has $interval: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Answer (score 38):

You can use `$timeout` as an interval.

```
var myIntervalFunction = function() {
    cancelRefresh = $timeout(function myFunction() {
        // do something
        cancelRefresh = $timeout(myIntervalFunction, 60000);
    },60000);
};
```

If the view is destroyed, you can destroy it with listening on `$destroy`:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(e) {
        $timeout.cancel(cancelRefresh);
});
```

Comment: I guess you misinterpreted the question. The setInterval() function of JS calls a function repetedly.

Comment: I know. At the moment there is no setInterval alternative in angular. The only way to simulate it is a $timeout function which calls itself recursively.

Comment: lets see how long it lasts before i start getting stackoverflow exceptions

Comment: @LeblancMeneses: there is no recursion here, so there won't be any stack overflow.

Comment: @KevinBeal: 'do something', whatever your function should do

Comment: This answer will wait double the time after the first run. See my answer below. The timeout is constructed to run in 1 minute. When 1 minute expires, it calls the action, then creates a timer that executes in 1 minute. When THAT 1 minute expires, it creates a new timer to run in 1 minute. 1 minute later, the "something" happens and the cycle repeats. The first run works, subsequent runs are double the wait time (2 minutes in this example). If you change line 4 (the second $timeout) to be a timeout of 1ms, the problem resolves without introducing a potential stack overflow.

Comment: @TylerForsythe you're right, I've reverted a change which incorrectly renamed `myFunction` to `myIntervalFunction`. There is however no issue with a stack overflow as each `$timeout` is not a recursive call but rather defers the execution of the provided function which will be executed with a new call stack.

Answer (score 32):

**Update**

Angular has implemented an $interval feature in version 1.2 - [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$interval](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24interval)

---

Legacy example below, disregard unless you're using a version older than 1.2.

A setInterval implementation in Angular -

I've created a factory called timeFunctions, which exposes $setInterval and $clearInterval.

Note that any time I've needed to modify scope in a factory I've passed it in. I am unsure if this meets the "Angular way" of doing things, but it works well.

```
app.factory('timeFunctions', [

  "$timeout",

  function timeFunctions($timeout) {
    var _intervals = {}, _intervalUID = 1;

    return {

      $setInterval: function(operation, interval, $scope) {
        var _internalId = _intervalUID++;

        _intervals[ _internalId ] = $timeout(function intervalOperation(){
            operation( $scope || undefined );
            _intervals[ _internalId ] = $timeout(intervalOperation, interval);
        }, interval);

        return _internalId;
      },

      $clearInterval: function(id) {
        return $timeout.cancel( _intervals[ id ] );
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Example Usage:

```
app.controller('myController', [

  '$scope', 'timeFunctions',

  function myController($scope, timeFunctions) {

    $scope.startFeature = function() {

      // scrollTimeout will store the unique ID for the $setInterval instance
      return $scope.scrollTimeout = timeFunctions.$setInterval(scroll, 5000, $scope);

      // Function called on interval with scope available
      function scroll($scope) {
        console.log('scroll', $scope);
        $scope.currentPage++;

      }
    },

    $scope.stopFeature = function() {
      return timeFunctions.$clearInterval( $scope.scrollTimeout );
    }

  }
]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Could you call a normal JavaScript method and then within that method wrap the Angular code with an $apply?

### Example

```
timer = setInterval('Repeater()', 50);

var Repeater = function () {
  // Get Angular scope from a known DOM element
  var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById(elem)).scope();
  scope.$apply(function () {
    scope.SomeOtherFunction();
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Latest release candidate (1.2.0 rc3) has [interval](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/2b5ce84fca7b41fca24707e163ec6af84bc12e83) support. See [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)