# AngularJS notifying view of changes to model

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, angularjs, controller, setinterval

I'm trying to display the current time in a view based on a Javascript Date object in my controller. My controller looks like this:

```
myApp.controller('DateCtrl', function($scope) {
    var date = new Date();
    $scope.minutes = date.getMinutes();
    $scope.hours = date.getHours();
    $scope.seconds = date.getSeconds();
    var updateTime = function() {
        var date2 = new Date();
        $scope.minutes = date2.getMinutes();
        $scope.hours = date2.getHours();
        $scope.seconds = date2.getSeconds();
    }
    $scope.clickUpdate = function() {
        setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
    }
});
```

In my view I simply have:

```
<div ng-controller="DateCtrl">
    <div>This is the hour: {{ hours }}</div>
    <div>This is the minute: {{ minutes }}</div>
    <div>This is the second: {{ seconds }}</div>
    <button ng-click="clickUpdate()">Click Update Here!</button>
</div>
```

For some reason, the `setInterval()` method works only once and I can't get it to keep running `updateTime()` every 1 second as was set. I put in a simple `console.log()` statement and that ran every 1 second...so I'm very confused.

I've also checked out `$scope.watch()` and `$scope.digest()` but I'm not quite sure how they can be used/if I'm supposed to use them in this scenario.

**EDIT: Upon further inspection, it appears as if the `setInterval` is working properly, calling `updateTime()` every 1 second, but the values in the scope aren't being reflected in my view after every call.**

Comment: `setInterval(updateTime, 1000)`

Comment: For some reason it has the same behavior whether I use "updateTime()" or "updateTime", it doesn't continue to update itself.

Comment: Update the scope values _inside_ the `updateTime` function.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused, aren't the values in my scope being updated inside updateTime currently? They are within the function I'm setting equal to "var updateTime".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you are changing the scope from *outside the angular world* (setInterval). You must `$apply` the changes:

```
var updateTime = function() {
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        var date2 = new Date();
        $scope.minutes = date2.getMinutes();
        $scope.hours = date2.getHours();
        $scope.seconds = date2.getSeconds();
    });
}
```

or use a *angular aware* function such as `$timeout`. Check @asgoth answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237070/using-setinterval-in-angularjs-factory) to create an *angular aware* `setInterval()` function.

Comment: $scope.$apply causes a call to $digest, the whole process causes a "validation" or rather fires all the watches for anything that has had scope changes.  Thing in angular such as $timeout or $http simply already have this code.  Passing a function to $scope.$apply() rather than calling it with no arguments allows Angular to handle wrapping error handling around any code execution.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use `$scope.$digest()`  after you change model , but I think `$scope.$apply` is better