# Angular 6 mat table DOM not updating after splicing the data source

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a `mat-table`

```html
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="orders" [trackBy]="$index">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="deliver_on">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Deliver On </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [style.color]="row.deliver_on"> {{row.deliver_on}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>


    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row [ngClass]="row.highlight_row"  *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

</mat-table>
<mat-paginator [length]="pageLength" [pageSize]="pageSize" (page)="next($event)">
</mat-paginator>
```

I want to update the rows within a certain logic.

However when I update the datasource (ARRAY SPLICE), the DOM is not changing

```js
var order = data.payload.order;
var index = this.orders.findIndex((orders) => orders.id === order.id);

Object.defineProperty(order, "highlight_row", {
    value: 'highlight_row',
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});

if (index > -1) {
    // update at same position
    this.orders.splice(index, 1, order);
}
else {
    this.orders = [...this.orders, order];
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS notifying view of changes to model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848063/angularjs-notifying-view-of-changes-to-model)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the material **cdk** documentation and exactly in the `@Input() dataSource: CdkTableDataSourceInput<T>` :

> If a data array is provided, the table must be notified when the
>   array's objects are added, removed, or moved. This can be done by
>   calling the renderRows() function which will render the diff since the
>   last table render. If the data array reference is changed, the table
>   will automatically trigger an update to the rows.

Also, in a JavaScript point of view, the `splice` method mutates (changes) the array, so the array reference is not changed.

Ref: https://material.angular.io/cdk/table/api

Answer (score 3):

after you changed the elements in your `MatTableDataSource` you can force your table to redraw with

```
this.order._updateChangeSubscription();
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably have to fire the changedetetor manually after splice

```
if (index > -1) {
    // update at same position
    this.orders.splice(index, 1, order);
    this.changeDetectorRefs.detectChanges();
}
```