# How do you write a "Hello, world!" for Comet in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, comet

I've looked and haven't been able to find out how to handle a basic Comet proof-of-concept in AngularJS. I'm looking at Comet implemented by the client making repeated Ajax calls, rather than streaming JavaScript.

If I have a server-side CGI:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: application/json"
echo ""
echo "'"Hello world at "`/bin/date`"'!'"'"
```

What is a bare-bones AngularJS proof of concept that will query the server every second, and modulo network latency and the like, display a "Hello world!" that includes the server time?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "modulo network latency and the like" are you just looking for an example of how to make an async call from Angular?

Comment: A recurring async call, yes. On a real network, network latency and other conditions could mar an app's behavior as showing server time; I was basically trying to say, "Disregarding other nuances, how could an AngularJS Comet be written that would consume the CGI script's output and display the server time?"

Answer (score 0):

The Plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/6kpLplq5hy9e2sXMaEsG?p=preview

The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.15" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    {{data.theDate}}
  </body>

</html>
```

The JS

```
angular.module("myApp", []).service("UpdatingService", function($http, $timeout){
  var service = {
    data:{},

    getData:function(){
      $http.get("someData.json").success(function(result){
        angular.copy(result, service.data)
        service.data.theDate+="    "+new Date();
      });
    }
  };

  cancelRefresh = $timeout(function myFunction() {
      service.getData();
      cancelRefresh = $timeout(myFunction, 1000);
  },1000);


  return service;
}).controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, UpdatingService){
  $scope.data = UpdatingService.data;
});
```

So I show how I would generally do this above.  First create a service that handles doing the request and storing the data.  Then make a controller and inject said service.  Within the service inject the $http and $timeout services from angular so we can make the ajax request and can repeat the request thereby polling the server.  Since there's no real setInterval the $timeout callback creates a new $timeout to continue the cycle, you can use the cancelRefresh if you need to stop the timer at some point details on that in the link below.

[using setInterval in angularjs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237070/using-setinterval-in-angularjs-factory)