# Why are angular variables reset with $interval/$timeout?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timer

I've been working on a simple stopwatch like timer app as a way to get familiar with Angular JS. With the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply) ([How do I use $scope.$watch and $scope.$apply in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply)) I was able to get two different variables on the javascript side to synchronize with one another on a change using $watch.  I use these to display different formats of the start time.

Then I wanted to use the same approach to update the current position.  Initially I was using setInterval and clearInterval to handle the timer updates.  In that case, $watch was not catching the updates and the DOM was not being changed.

This question pointed out that Angular has custom $timeout and $interval functions which take care of $apply and $watch updates:

[using setInterval in angularjs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237070/using-setinterval-in-angularjs-factory)

I had some trouble using $interval.  I was getting "$interval is not defined". To make it available, I passed it in as part of the controller function definition:

```
app.controller("MainController", function($scope, $interval){
   ...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6zJmS/9/

This all works as expected in the above fiddle, but when I run it locally the start and position variables get reset to 0 when I start the timer.  The timer continues to run and log to the console, but before that happens I see the unexpected reset:

```
Updating set_to to 10 app.js:52
start called app.js:76
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. angular.js:2606
Updating hms to 00:00:00 app.js:46
Updating set_to to 0 app.js:52
Updating hms to 00:00:00 app.js:46
9
```

Any ideas why I'm seeing the reset locally?

P.S.

Along the way I found a much more polished implementation of a timer using Angular JS, in case that's what you're actually looking for:

http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/

https://github.com/siddii/angular-timer

Thanks!

Edit:
In case it helps, I've posted the full code here:
https://github.com/charlesbrandt/timer

Comment: I don't see what's the problem with your fiddle. What exactly do you mean by "unexpected reset". Which line in that console output makes you think you have an "unexpected reset"?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't happen in the fiddle unfortunately, only when I run it locally.  The console output is from the local run.  In the fiddle I don't see "Updating hms to 00:00:00 app.js:46" after I press start.

Comment: What version of angular do you have locally @Charles Brandt, and is it the same version being loaded in the fiddle?

Comment: AngularJS v1.2.11, so I guess a bit newer than the fiddle.